# Angular: Catch the time of last click on a function

Tags: angular

Using this program I can set the volume by clicking Up/Down button. For set a volume I need to click those buttons for several times. Now I want to know the last click time of Adjust() function, if the time is 5 seconds it will hit a function. Which function print a console log.

A scenario: At first volume is 5. I update it to 10 by 5 clicks on Adjust(). Now a function check the last click time, if the time is 5 seconds it call a function which have a "console.log('volume updated')" . After some time if I change the volume again, System will need to do the same things.

[Stackblitz Code Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1w51wz)

Comment: Could you clarify you question ? Are you asking for time elapsed or are you aksing for last click time

Comment: Still didn't understand your question, Could you please elaborate ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you, this is what you need

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  Vol= 5
  timer:Observable<any>;
  subscription = null;

Adjust(event){
    const target = event.target || event.currentTarget;
    const idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    const VolId = idAttr.nodeValue;
    if (VolId === 'up') {
      this.Vol++;
    } else {
      this.Vol--;
    }


    if(this.subscription != null) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    this.timer = timer(5000);
    this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe(
      v=>{
        console.log(v)
      }

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set a static variable that holds the last time of click. Like `static lastClick = null`; Then on click update the value `AppComponent.lastClick = Date.now()`. Then you can compare when it was last clicked by `Date.now() - AppComponent`. Date.now() returns in milliseconds though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to call `adjust` only if the time elapsed since the last click on any of the Up or Down buttons is 5 sec.

To achieve that, you can store the last clicked timestamp and every time a button is clicked compare the last time stamp with the current one and check to see if the difference is more than 5000. This will translate to code like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  vol = 5
  lastClickTimestamp = 0;

  callAdjustIfIntervalAchieved(buttonName) {
    const currentTimeStamp = Date.now();
    if(currentTimeStamp - this.lastClickTimestamp > 5000) {
      this.lastClickTimestamp = currentTimeStamp;
      this.adjust(buttonName);
    }
  }

  adjust(buttonName) {
    buttonName === 'up' ? this.vol++ : this.vol--;
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<button (click)="callAdjustIfIntervalAchieved('up')">Volume Up</button>
<button (click)="callAdjustIfIntervalAchieved('down')">Volume Down</button>
<p>{{vol}}</p>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/volume-up-or-down-only-after-5-sec?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.